# OpenWind Unable to open polygon shp files from QGIS

Tags: qgis-processing, error, openwind

I have a set of interlinked lines shp files which i imported to QGIS and add a fixed buffered zone via vector processing function on QGIS 3.10.
I saved the scratch layer and toggled edit off on polygon layer and then try to open this save layer in Openwind but got this error message: "Record found which is a different type (0) to that in main header (5) ERROR: Unexpected end of text."

Can i please ask for some help to see what have i done wrong and how can i correct this issue? This does not appear to be an issue with i deal with point layers so far (also used QGIS to add buffer)

"[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shape types are documented in http://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/mo_/shapefile.pdf

```
Value Shape Type
0 Null Shape
1 Point
3 PolyLine
5 Polygon
8 MultiPoint
11 PointZ
13 PolyLineZ
15 PolygonZ
18 MultiPointZ
21 PointM
23 PolyLineM
25 PolygonM
28 MultiPointM
31 MultiPatch
```

It seems that your process has yielded some empty geometries. They are valid in shapefile but obviously Openwind does not like them.